# Deploying Service Cloud for Slack settings

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

After setting up Swarming and Service Cloud for Slack in my dev environment, I'd like to deploy the settings to the rest of my DevOps pipeline. Is this possible?

(I've looked high and low in the Metadata API doc and found nothing either under Settings, Slack, Collaboration or Swarming; The [Unsupported Metadata Types page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) is silent.

*(I'm going to assume this can't be done and the set up has to be repeated in each DevOps pipeline org)*

### [image]

### [image]

### [[image: Slack record layouts][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7maO.png)

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be NO - you can't deploy as of V59 `Service Cloud for Slack` or `Swarming` settings.  Some of this may be related to accepting the Terms and Conditions requirement for `Service Cloud for Slack` setup.

I ended up manually repeating all my setup steps in each org of my DevOps Pipeline

*Ideally, in some future release this will change and someone will provide a new Answer indicating so*